# The use of HTTP headers

Tags: http, header, request, response

In [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) says:

> HTTP headers allow the client and the server to pass additional
>   information with the request or the response

but I don't understand what is the use of that? What is the need to pass additional information with the request or the response?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a hard question to answer concisely because of the many different types of HTTP headers and what they do, but here's an attempt at a one-line answer:

*HTTP headers allow a client and server to understand each other better, meaning they can communicate more effectively.*

So then if you look at individual headers, it becomes clearer why each is needed:

**User-Agent header**

- Sent by the client
- Tells the server about the client's setup (browser, OS etc.)
- Mostly used to improve client experience, e.g. tailoring responses for mobile devices or dealing with browser compatibility issues

**set-cookie header**

- Sent by the server
- Tells the browser to set a cookie

**host header**

- Sent by the client
- Specifies the exact domain name of the site the client wants to reach, this is used when a single server hosts multiple websites (a.k.a. virtual hosting)